# how to remove spaces and numbers without at spcial char?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have string like this pattern and i want to

**income_statement@Other Income (Minority Interest)@9**

- remove numbers
- remove special chars except @
- replace spaces with underscores

i do something like this but it was not work yet

```
$spaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $key);
 echo  $numbers = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", "_", $spaces);
```

Comment: `/[^a-zA-Z@_]/` or `preg_replace("/\d+|\s+/", '')`

Comment: What is the final expected output? `income_statement@Other_Income_Minority_Interest@`?

Comment: () still found in output like this  Other_Income_(Minority_Interest)

Comment: and it was add underscore in the finish of letter like this  _Fiscal_Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIRST STEP** (remove numbers, every non letter, note that this include the underscore `_` too but not simple whitespace)

```
$re = "/(?:[^a-z@ ]|\d)/i";
$str = "income_statement@Other Income (Minority Interest)@9"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:

```
incomestatement@Other Income Minority Interest@
```

**SECOND STEP** (sub spaces with underscore `_`)

```
$re = "/\s+/";
$str = "incomestatement@Other Income Minority Interest@";
$subst = "_"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Output:

```
incomestatement@Other_Income_Minority_Interest@
```

**COMPACT VERSION**

```
$str = "income_statement@Other Income (Minority Interest)@9";
$stripped = preg_replace("/(?:[^a-z@ ]|\d)/i", "", $str);
$result = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $stripped);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// this should work and replace all spaces with underscores
$spaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $key);

// you have to add the @ and the underscores in your expression
// and replace it with an empty string
echo  $numbers = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z@_]/', '', $spaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it done with two **preg_replace** and one **str_replace** :

```
$str = 'income_statement@Other Income (Minority Interest)@9';
 // Change space to underscore
 $str = str_replace(' ','_',$str);
 // Remove all numbers
$str = preg_replace('/[\d]+/','',$str);
// Remove all characters except words and @ in UTF-8 mode
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w@]+/u','',$str);

// Print it out
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z@ ]+/", '', $data); // remove all except letters and @ (if you want keep \n and \t just add it in pattern)
$data = str_replace(' ', '_', $data);
```